# Display/ Hide Markers on Video based on current time Javascript

Tags: javascript, annotations, html5-video

I am trying to implement a function that displays/ hides markers (could be subtitles, highlighted area) based on "timeUpdate" event which tracks current time.

My content source has multiple tracks. Based on current time, one or more tracks containing marker objects may be shown or hidden.

Here's the starter code. I only trying to implement an efficient algorithm which can be scalable in case number of tracks increase. Need suggestions on improvements

```
player.on('timeUpdate', function(event) {
    // currentTime (seconds, float) is exposed as event.data.currentTime
    var currentTime = event.data.currentTime;
    var time = convertTimeStamp(currentTime);
    // your algorithm will be called here with the currentTime as the argument
    handleAnnotations(time);
});

function handleAnnotations(currentTime) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < tracks.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < tracks[i].length; j++) {
            var currentAnnotationStartTime = convertTimeStamp(tracks[i][j].startTime);
            var currentAnnotationEndTime = convertTimeStamp(tracks[i][j].endTime);
            if (currentTime >= currentAnnotationStartTime && currentTime < currentAnnotationEndTime) {
                tracks[i][j].show;
            } else {
                tracks[i][j].hide;
            }
        }
    }
}

function convertTimeStamp(time) {
    var hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60);
    var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    var seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60);
    var hourValue = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var minuteValue = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    var secondValue = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

    var mediaTime = `${hourValue}:${minuteValue}:${secondValue}`;
    return mediaTime;
}
```

Tracks are setup like this:

```
tracks =    [
                [annotation1, annotation2, annotationN...],
                [annotation1, annotation2, annotationN...], ... 
            ]
```

Where each `annotation` looks like:

```
{
     "startTime": timestamp,
     "endTime": timestamp,
     "show": fn,
     "hide": fn 
}
```

Comment: What is the problem **exactly**? You need an **IF** statement. `if ( currentTime >= currentExpectedTime ) { /* do something */ }` where the **currentExpectedTime** is a number (seconds or millisecs) from a list (Array) of times to "do something".

Comment: @VC.One: Sorry, I've updated the post. I'm trying to implement an algorithm that displays/ hides annotations based on current time from multiple tracks.

Comment: Sorry for the quiet but still not sure what the exact problem is (have you had any issues when trying to scale up?). Anyways if this was my problem... **(1)** Before play begins I would simply note the "expected next timestamp" for the next-to-shown Annotation. Then video's timeUpdate simply gives a reason to show that Annotation. Repeat for future annotations. **(2)** Is your IF statement trying to compare text Strings as if they were Numbers? That won't work. You need to keep the display times in seconds (or milliseconds) or convert from text like HH:MM:SS into secs/msecs.